# Como imprimir partituras de músicas em PDF?

Tags: html, impressão

Estou desenvolvendo um website para uma igreja onde em uma determinada parte do website será disponibilizado partituras de músicas para os integrantes da orquestra, e eu não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso. Eu estava pensando em utilizar a classe `mPDF` para poder aproveitar a função de download que a classe já oferece, mais não sei se daria certo por que eu não saberia como demarcar as notas nas pautas da partitura no `HTML`, para poder apresenta-las na classe `mPDF`.

Eu estou precisando de um norte para poder desenvolver isso, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você já possui os arquivos? Você precisa apenas saber como fazer a solicitação de impressão é isso?

Comment: @ErlonCharles eu não tenho esses arquivos, qual é a extensão desses arquivos? Na verdade eu gostaria de fazer algo parecido com isto:  (https://musopen.org/sheetmusic/40128/ernest-walker/viola-sonata-op29/). Vc tem noção de como se faz isto?

Comment: Neste exemplo que você deu ele está usando o código de integração do Google drive para fazer a exibição do PDF, mas você também pode usar o [PDFJS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) que a algum tempo é e extenção nativa de exibição de PDF do Firefox, mas é possível utilizar em su sistema

Comment: Ok @ErlonCharles, eu entendi, mais enquanto as partituras? Ela vão ser uma imagem?

Comment: As partituras estão dentro do arquivo PDF, elas não são geradas. Era isso que você estava pensando?

Comment: Primeiramente você precisa considerar a partitura como um PDF normal. Eu já utilizei muita partitura e todas eram PDF. Então na area administrativa tenha um campo de upload de arquivo. Eu faria isso.

Comment: é um trabalho e tanto.. há alguns meios para resolver. Pode fazer com HTML5 canvas, imagens estáticas ou imagens vetoriais como o svg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o [VexFlow](http://www.vexflow.com/) para montar a partituras. Com o HTML montado basta gerar o PDF.

É simples a utilização do VexFlow, primeiro crie o elemento HTML:

```
<canvas width=700 height=100"></canvas>
```

Agora basta renderizar:

```
var canvas = $("div.one div.a canvas")[0];
var renderer = new Vex.Flow.Renderer(canvas,
Vex.Flow.Renderer.Backends.CANVAS);

var ctx = renderer.getContext();
var stave = new Vex.Flow.Stave(10, 0, 500);
stave.addClef("treble").setContext(ctx).draw();
```

Veja o [exemplo completo aqui](http://www.vexflow.com/docs/tutorial.html). Acesse o [Repositorio oficial](https://github.com/0xfe/vexflow)